# Initcap of word

Tags: sql, string, hiveql

I'm having a table x it contain the column `resource_name` in this column I'm having data like NASRI(SRI).
I'm applying initcap on this column it's giving output `Nasri(sri)`. But my expected output is `Nasri(Sri)`.
How I can achieve the desired result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `split()` with `concat_ws()`. If value does not contain '()', then it will also work correctly. Demo with ():

```
hive> select  concat_ws('(',initcap(split('NASRI(SRI)','\\(')[0]), 
                            initcap(split('NASRI(SRI)','\\(')[1])
                       );
OK
Nasri(Sri)
Time taken: 0.974 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

And for value without () it also works good:

```
hive> select concat_ws('(',initcap(split('NASRI','\\(')[0]),
                           initcap(split('NASRI','\\(')[1])
                      );
OK
Nasri
Time taken: 0.697 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```